# How to match 0 or more than 1 occurence of whitespace

Tags: regex, vim

I want to use regex to match the following strings:

`blub{` (no intervening space) and `blub  {` (two intervening spaces) and `blub   {` (three intervening spaces) and so on but not  `blub {` (one intervening space)

In the moment I can match `blub{` with `/\S{/` and the rest with  `/\S \{2,}{/` in my vimrc file.
However I cannot combine these to regex expressions in vim. How can I achieve this?

The aim is to mark in my cpp files all lines where the bracket has not a space between.

Comment: Refine your formating... it is not clear how many spaces are allowed.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can have several spaces in stackoverflow?

Comment: Try this: - `/\S(| {2,})\{/`

Comment: @tune2fs you need to backslash the “(|)”.

Comment: Where to put backslahses depends on your current level of magic.

Comment: @tune2fs, your update is not needed. Check the proper answer instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use alternatives.

```
/\S\(\| \{2,}\){/
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
/\S\(\s\{2,}\)\?{/
```

This says zero-or-one of 2+ whitespaces, which skips the one-space possibility

Comment: You need the backslashes, but nice one though.

Comment: @tune2fs:, there was a backslash missing before `?` and before `S`.